# How to display information when data can not be loaded in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I have been making a large JavaScript file and often encounter errors.
To make error finding easier I have made it so the page writes on the page if an area has been successful in loading.
However, the code is being changed and so I can no longer write to the page until the end.
Is there any way to provide information so I can find out where the error occurred?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com) to view the javascript console and debug errors. You can also use the `console.log` function on variables to print their value to the console as follows:

```
 console.log(var);
```

Comment: i agree with Tom. firebug is best

Answer (score 1):

Again, I agree with @Tom. Using:
`console.log("something goes here");`
and either firebug or [Chrome's dev tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) (inspector) is probably the best way to go.

Otherwise, a less elegant approach would be to use alerts:
`alert("something...");`